# How to test not finding files on classpath? java (spring @Configuration)

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit, classpath

I would like to test that a spring

```
@Configuration class
```

can handle missing files on the classpath. E.g. when using PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer. But this is just a specific example, the question is really about how to test classes that interact with the classpath (e.g. read a file located in src/main/resources in a maven project).

So in essence I would like to create a spring context where I control the classpath in the test set up code.

The test needs to be a JUnit test.

Answer (score 1):

Hope below may help you

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:/testApplicationContext.xml"})
public class YourTestClass{
```

you have to create a spring context for your test and you can include the production one into it. you can replace `classpath*:` with a absolute location.

Regards, Rajib.

Comment: I would like to programatically change the classpath. Something like (pseudocode):

     classpath = classpath.remove("foo.properties")

Answer (score 0):

This work if it's a maven project:

- move the classpath file that you want to test the absence from to a separate pom jar module, and include it wherever needed.
- move the classpath test to a separate pom jar module named missing-classpath-file-test, but don't include the module with the file that you want to simulate as missing. I will be missing from the classpath only for that test.

When running missing-classpath-file-test, the file will not be on the classpath, and the error you need to reproduce is achieved.

Concerning the question on the comment bellow, with the class loaders that come with application servers and the one used on a junit test it's not possible to programmatically change the classpath.